# Independent Bernoulli Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question is:

Let $X_k$, $k = 1,2,...$ be independent Bernoulli distributed random variables such that

$$P(X_k=1) = p, P(X_k=0)=1-p, \ \ k=1,2,..., \ \ 0\lt p \lt 1$$

Let
$$Y_m= \prod_{k=1}^m X_k,\ \ \ m \ge 1  $$

a. Compute $E[Y_m]$ for any $m \ge 1$ and also find $\lim_{m\to \inf} E[Y_m]$.

b. Compute $VAR[Y_m]$ for any $m \ge 1$ and also find $\lim_{m\to \inf} VAR[Y_m]$.

c. Compute $E[Y_mY_n]$ for any $m,n \ge 1$.

I think that (a) is $E[X_1]=p$ and they are independent that I can just multiply the expected value to be $E[Y_m]=p^m$ and as $\lim_{m\to \inf} E[Y_m] = 0$

I think that (b) is similar as (a), $VAR[X_1]=p(1-p)$. Again using the independent rule we have $VAR[Y_m]=(p(1-p))^m$, but I am not for sure.

I think that (c) is similar as above and $E[Y_mY_n]=p^mp^n$, but I don't have confidence.

Comment: Hint: For every $k$, $$X_k^2=X_k.$$

Comment: Hint to answer the question in a comment to the posted answer: As a consequence to the previous hint, $$Y_mY_n=Y_{\max(n,m)}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b. Using the definition formula for $\text{Var}$ (Notice that it's incorrect to have that $\text{Var}(X_1 X_2) = \text{Var}(X_1)\text{Var}(X_2)$, only expectation operator $E$ factorize under independence assumption):
\begin{align}
& \text{Var}[Y_m] = \text{Var}\left[\prod_{k = 1}^m X_k\right]\\
= & E\left[\prod_{k = 1}^m X_k^2\right] - \left\{E\left[\prod_{k = 1}^m X_k\right]\right\}^2 \\
= & \prod_{k = 1}^m E[X_k^2] - p^{2m} \\
= & [p(1 - p) + p^2]^m - p^{2m} \\
= & p^m - p^{2m}.
\end{align}

c. can be dealt similarly: simplify $Y_mY_n$ first (discuss if $m = n$), just keep in mind that $E(X_jX_k)$ factorize to $E(X_j)E(X_k)$ only if $j \neq k$.

Comment: I think I got a better handle on it for when $m=n$ then $E[Y_mY_n]=p^m$ but when $m≠n$ then I think that $E[Y_mY_n]=p^{max(m,n)}$. Is that correct?